# Removing '#' from the scraped links

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi I am beginner with web scraping. I am trying to scrape all the links from a website and I am successful to some extent.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.marian.ac.in/'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

soup.title
soup.title.string

for link in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
    print(link['href'])
```

The issue I am facing is the output has '#'.How shall I remove this?

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: `print(link['href'].replace('#', ''))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The # entries you are getting are actually from some href entries. Screenshot attached from the website. We can simply filter them out by adding an if condition inside for loop like this.

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if not link['href'].strip() == "#":
        print(link['href'])
```

This will return few non url entries like "javascript:void(0);" or "semester-register-login" as well. If We don't want those entries as well we need to modify the condition.

[image]

Comment: How to modify to remove non url entries and why does it return non url entries when href is set as True?

Comment: When we are setting 'href == True' it is basically applying the filter to find out the elements which have href attribute. Since those elements have href attribute they are also being returned. on further inspection we can see that the non-urls that we are talking about are actually partial url. For Example, upon clicking on the element with href value as 'semester-register-login', we land on "https://www.marian.ac.in/semester-register-login"

Comment: If we don't want those "#" and partial urls, we can change the condition to 'link['href'].startswith("http")'. That should filter out any partial url and javascript snippets.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following to get the links that do not starts with `#`. You can choose either of the conditions to meet the requirement:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.marian.ac.in/'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
    if link['href'].strip().startswith("#"):continue
    # if not link['href'].startswith("http"):continue
    print(link['href'])
```